# Filter WPF DataGrid based on TextBoxes and CheckBoxes MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I was hoping to get it working myself but it looks like I am missing something still. I have 4 TextBoxes for filtering WPF DataGrid. In addition to them I have 2 CheckBoxes.

Currently I am not getting any errors, but

1. I can only check CheckBox and can't uncheck.

[image]

2. If both Checkboxes are checked = "filters applied" and value is entered to YRNRO "applying more filters" = "inputting values" to other TextBoxes does nothing. Are filters getting messed because of that?

   ```
        string ACTIVEBoolquery = ACTIVEBool ? "AND YRNRO Like '6%' OR YRNRO Like '7%'" : "";

        this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter =
          $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'" +
          ACTIVEBoolquery;
   ```

I would like to have CheckBox filters inside `EnableRowFiltering` to cover situation when CheckBoxes are chekced before loading the data. So I can check CheckBox and then load data to DataGrid with calling `EnableRowFiltering` after loading data.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <!--CHECKBOXES-->

    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MyCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding ACTIVEBool}" x:Name="ActiveCustomer" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MyCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding FIANDSEBool}" x:Name="OnlyFIandSE" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Here is my current code ViewModel.cs:

```
    // Binding checkbox FIANDSE Bool
    private bool _FIANDSEBool;
    public bool FIANDSEBool
    {
        get => this._FIANDSEBool;
        set
        {
            this._FIANDSEBool = true;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            // Refresh the DataTable filter expression
            EnableRowFiltering();
        }
    }

    // Binding checkbox ACTIVE Bool
    private bool _ACTIVEBool;
    public bool ACTIVEBool
    {
        get => this._ACTIVEBool;
        set
        {
            this._ACTIVEBool = true;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            // Refresh the DataTable filter expression
            EnableRowFiltering();
        }
    }

    public void EnableRowFiltering()
    {
        string FIANDSEBoolquery = FIANDSEBool ? "AND KAYTOSSA LIKE '%1%'" : "";
        string ACTIVEBoolquery = ACTIVEBool ? "AND YRNRO Like '6%' OR YRNRO Like '7%'" : "";

        this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter =
          $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'" +
          $"AND HAKUNIMI LIKE '{this.HAKUNIMISearchKey}*'" +
          $"AND KONSERNI LIKE '{this.GROUPSearchKey}*'" +
          $"AND LY LIKE '{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}*'" +
          FIANDSEBoolquery + ACTIVEBoolquery;
    }
```

Comment: You should use the equals (double `==`) operator to compare values: `_FIANDSEBool == true`. How does it crash? What does the exception message say?

Comment: `FIANDSEBool == true` is a redundant comparison. Just write `FIANDSEBool ? "" : ...`.

Comment: I believe checkboxes in WPF are nullable (checked, unchecked and undefined) so you may need to bind them to bool? instead of bool.  Is your property getting hit when you check/uncheck the box? Put a breakpoint in there to make sure the binding is working.  Do the text boxes work? is it only the checkboxes that aren't working?

Comment: Add some space before `AND` like `"  AND KAYTOSSA LIKE"`

Comment: @hatman: What does "can't uncheck" mean?

Comment: @mm8 If I check it once, it stays as it is. If I click CheckBox again (no matter how many times)  it is still checked. Something to do with `IsChecked="{Binding ACTIVEBool}"`? It looks like `IsChecked` is always true after you have clicked it once.

Comment: @hatman: So where do you set the data-bound `bool` property?

Comment: @mm8 I have updated my question with checkbox behavior.

Comment: @hatman: Post your updated and current code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignments

```
this._FIANDSEBool = true;
```

and

```
this._ACTIVEBool = true;
```

in the property setters are obviously wrong.

They should use the `value` keyword instead:

```
public bool FIANDSEBool
{
    get => _FIANDSEBool;
    set
    {
        _FIANDSEBool = value; // here
        OnPropertyChanged();
        EnableRowFiltering();
    }
}
```